# Decide which labels to show in apexchart

Tags: apexcharts

I have the chart below. The series looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "x": 0,
    "y": 100
  },
  {
    "x": 0.5,
    "y": 200
  },
  {
    "x": 1,
    "y": 300
  },
  {
    "x": 1.5,
    "y": 400
  },
]
```

Now i want to show only *even* numbers in the xaxis labels, but still have the tooltip with the potentially uneven number.

Is there a way to achieve this?

[image: Example Chart]

Answer (score 1):

If you look at xaxis.label.formatter where you can pass a callback function. The function arguments are value (current xaxis label, timestamp and index of datapoint. You have to returned a formatted string from this function.

What you can do is check if 'value' is even or odd and then format it according and return the value.

Related link: https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/xaxis/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I want to do though is to show nothing at the xaxis for uneven numbers. When I add a formatter that returns an empty String in that case, there is also no value at the tooltip when you hover.